# Spring Mvc with Thread

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi My thread class is showing null pointer exception please help me to resolve

```
@Component
public class AlertsToProfile extends Thread {

    public  final Map<Integer, List<String>> userMessages = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>());

    @Autowired
    ProfileDAO profileDAO;

    private String categoryType;

    private String dataMessage;

    public String getCategoryType() {
        return categoryType;
    }

    public void setCategoryType(String categoryType) {
        this.categoryType = categoryType;
    }

    public String getDataMessage() {
        return dataMessage;
    }

    public void setDataMessage(String dataMessage) {
        this.dataMessage = dataMessage;
    }

    public void run() {

                String category=getCategoryType();
                String data= getDataMessage();
                List<Profile> all = profileDAO.findAll();
                if (all != null) {
                    if (category == "All" || category.equalsIgnoreCase("All")) {
                        for (Profile profile : all) {
                            List<String> list = userMessages.get(profile.getId());
                            if (list == null ) {
                                ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
                                strings.add(data);
                                userMessages.put(profile.getId(), strings);
                            } else {
                                list.add(data);
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
             }
```

and my service method is as follows

```
@Service
public class NoteManager
{


    @Autowired  AlertsToProfile alertsToProfile;

    public void addNote(String type, String message, String category) {

        alertsToProfile.setCategoryType(category);
        String data = type + "," + message;
        alertsToProfile.setDataMessage(data);

       alertsToProfile.start();
        System.out.println("addNotes is done");
    }
```

But when i call start() method am getting null pointer exception please help me. I am new to spring with thread concept

Comment: please post the complete stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It pretty obvious: you instantiate your thread directly, as opposed to letting spring create AlertsToProfile and auto wire your instance.

To fix this, create a Runnable around your run() method and embed that into a method, something like this:

```
public void startThread() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your code in here

        }}).start();
}
```

you will want to bind the Thread instance to a field in AlertsToProfile in order to avoid leaks and stop the thread when you're done.

Comment: _you instantiate your thread directly_ - `@Autowired  AlertsToProfile alertsToProfile`